# How to keep Eclipse CDT from resolving files outside of the configured include path?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have a project that containst source/header files that are from 3rd party. In my project I have the same filename in a different path (e.g. version.h). The scanner is resolving the includes to the wrong file and therefore fails to parse my source files properly.

That's what I have done:

- I explicitly configured the project path to not be part of the source path.
- Third party libraries are not on include path nor on source path (but a still a subfolder in the project).
- The toolchain is "No ToolChain", as it is a NMAKE project created by CMake.
- The include directories has been hand selected to exclude not wanted includes and explicitly add wanted includes.

How can I force eclipse to only resolve the files based on the configured include and source pathes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try turning off *Allow heuristic resolution of includes*. This is a global setting in Preferences -> *C/C++* -> *Indexer*. It can also be overridden per project in the project's settings.
[image: Allow heuristic resolution of includes]